# Close android service with a password

Tags: android, passwords, android-service

I'm working on android application which have one service runs in background,
I need to make sure that the user will close the app/service only upon inserting password (like app lock on the market only for the service and the app). 
Any ideas suggestion of how to implement such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

On android 2.3 isn't possible the user will kill your app, but starting with Android 4.0 and Device Administrator it is: reasonable. Take a look at Kaspersky's parental control app.